# Collection.removeIf works strangely

Tags: java, arraylist

I have ArrayList of lines from file.
File contains lines with 5 numbers:

```
1 1 13 25 25
25 25 11 3 1
25 25 13 1 1
```

And I have function test(String) to test if I need this line or if I have to remove it from list.
My test method:

```
static boolean test(String s){
        return list.contains(reverse(s));
}
```

reverse(String) returns line with numbers written in reverse order.
For `1 1 13 25 25` it will return `25 25 13 1 1`.

So, I wrote code that uses Iterator to loop through list and remove elements.

```
Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    if(test(iter.next()))
        iter.remove();
}
```

This code works correctly.
But IDEA says that the loop can be replaced with Collection.removeIf call.
So, I tried to replace code above with this line:

```
list.removeIf(s->test(s));
```

But it gives me empty list. Why? What is the difference?

Also I tried to remove lines that contains certain characters using removeIf and it works correctly.
Here you can see all program : http://pastebin.com/bWw3cBXg.

My file http://pastebin.com/mEb5sBBJ(~17000 lines)

Comment: Sounds strange; from *looking* what you are doing ... it seems like a valid approach. Thus you might want to look into http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ... in order to provide a small example that can be used to **repro** your problem.

Comment: Could you show us the `test` method?

Comment: Thx for the `test` method. I would still like to see — and run — a complete example.

Comment: Should a line also be removed if it is the reverse of itself?

Comment: @tobias_k program should remove only first OR third line in this example

Comment: @Roki20121 That's not an answer to the question. If the file contains the line `1 2 3 2 1`, should that line be removed? Because your code (both version) will remove it.

Comment: well, I didn't think about that. Lines like in you example shouldn't be removed.

Answer (score 4):

You're iterating through the list (by calling `contains()` on it) while modifying it, which is generally a bad idea.

Your first algorithm tests if the first line, reversed, is contained in the list. It removes that line. Then it inspects the second (now first) line, and doesn't find a reversed line element, since the first one has already been removed.

The second algorithm is different: it iterates through the list and marks all the indices that must be removed. Then it removes all of them. The second line is the same as the first line reversed. Same for the third. So in the end, everything is reversed.

Although this behavior is not documented in removeIf, it complies with the general contract that predicates should be idempotent, which is not the case here. Calling the predicate on an element of the list doesn't return the same value depending on whether you already have removed another element of the list or not.

Comment: Shouldn't that still keep `25 25 11 3 1`?

Comment: A quick test confirms the behaviour of `removeIf()` that you describe (though I couldn’t read that from the docs). Surely in the OP’s example I will expect that it at least removes more elements than the loop does.

Comment: @tobias_k yes, indeed. I read the data too fast and thought that line was the same as the third one. But I guess the data in the example is not the actual one where he got an empty result. Since he still didn't post a complete test case, it's hard to know.